# Issues with Discord.js Number Guessing Game

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

so I'm trying to make a basic number guessing game in Discord.js. You know, the one where the bot chooses a random number 1-100 and you guess it, and the bot tells you if you're too high or too low. Since I'm a beginner to coding, I looked as some example code online and tried to tweak it a bit to fit with my bot setup (And yes, I'm gonna credit the original maker). Here's my command handler, which I have successfully used with other commands before:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'guess') {
        client.commands.get('guess').execute(message, args);
    }
    });
```

And this is the code in my guess.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'guess',
    description: "guess a number 1-100",
    execute(message, args) {
        var mes = message.content.split(" ");
        message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
        num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        guesses = 0;

        if (mes[0] == '!guess') {
            if (num == 0) 
            {
                message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
                num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                guesses = 0;
            }
            else if (mes[1] == num) 
            {
                guesses++;
                message.reply('You got it! Only took ' + guesses + ' tries.');
                message.reply('Picking a random number between 1 and 100');
                num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
                guesses = 0;
            }
            else if (mes[1] < num) {
                message.reply(mes[1] + ' is too low');
                guesses++;
            }
            else if (mes[1] > num) {
                message.reply(mes[1] + ' is too high');
                guesses++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So yeah. Basically what's supposed to happen is that when you run ?pick, the bot picks a number 1-100- starting the game. Then, you guess numbers by running ?guess (number). For example, to guess 50, you would run ?guess 50. There are no errors in the code. However, when I try to run the ?pick command, nothing happens. When I run ?guess or ?guess (number), the bot responds with "Picking a random number between 1 and 100". Can anyone tell me what the issue is? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This code is adding a check if the message content starts with `!guess`, but you are using `?guess`. You need to make an array of users currently guessing, and change the `if (... === "!guess")` to `if (usersGuessing.includes(message.author.id))`.